# Set with Optional

Tags: java, stream, option-type

I have this code:

```
if (myClass != null){
    myClass2.setId(myClass.getId());
    myClass2.setName(myClass.getName());
    myClass2.setPosition(myClass.getPosition());
}
```

I want to replace this code to this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(myClass)
```

and map this field from myClass to myClass2
How i can do it?

Comment: There’s no point in using an `Optional` here. Your code is fine. If you want it nicer, you may wrap the whole thing into a nice method in either `myClass` or `myClass2` (the latter if you want to wrap everything including the `if` statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to use:

```
Optional.ofNullable(myClass)
        .ifPresent(m -> {
            myClass2.setId(m.getId());
            myClass2.setName(m.getName());
            myClass2.setPosition(m.getPosition());
        });
```

---

For mapping I would suggest to read about [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/), it is a good tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply cloning myClass object then you can use [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method on optional like this:

```java
public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass(1,"abc");
        
        System.out.println(myClone(Optional.ofNullable(mc)));
        
        mc = null;
        System.out.println(myClone(Optional.ofNullable(mc)));

    }
    
    
    public static Optional<MyClass> myClone(Optional<MyClass> mc) {
        return mc.map(o->new MyClass(o.id(), o.name()));   //<-- do your mapping here
    }
}

record MyClass(int id, String name) {};
```

Output:

```
Optional[MyClass[id=1, name=abc]]
Optional.empty
```

I am using record MyClass for simplicity. 
`ifPresent` method takes [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) function and `map` method takes [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) funtion.